# give default string as output if command output is empty

Tags: bash, awk, pipe

I have a command that may have an empty string as output, I want that when I execute:

```
myCommand | something 'default'
```

It either returns the output of `myCommand` or `default` if the output was empty

I have tried `myCommand |awk '{if(\$0==""){print "default"}}'` but it doesn't always work.

Comment: You could assign the output to a variable, `var=$(myCommand)`, and then use parameter expansion: `echo "${var:-default}"`?

Comment: Does your command produce a massive amount of data if it produces _any_ output? What are you doing with the data later?

Comment: No, only a few lines, I am posting the output on slack

Comment: Are you trying to print `default` if `myCommand` produces **no output** or print `default` for every line that `myCommand` outputs that is empty or contains only white space or what? Please [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output for `something` as right now it's very unclear what you want.

Comment: Only if there is no output, but if there is a line with output all will have. Also, I do not have a lot of experience with bash scripting or awk ;)

Comment: and what if the command DOES produce output? Really, just update your question to show us what you want... See [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you mentioned `awk`, here's one way.

**Note** this is for *empty* output, i.e., print the default if `myCommand` outputs nothing at all.  If you want to handle a program that outputs a blank line, that's something different.

```
myCommand | awk -v def="default" '{print} END { if(NR==0) {print def} }'
```

`{print}` passes each input line through.  At the end (`END{...}`), `NR` is the number of input records, i.e., the number of lines received from `myCommand`.  This will be 0 if no output was printed by `myCommand`.  If so, print the value of `def`, assigned on the command line by `-v def="whatever text you want"`.

Tests:

```
$ awk -v def="default" '{print} END {if(NR==0) {print def}}' </dev/null
default
$ awk -v def="default" '{print} END {if(NR==0) {print def}}' <<<'foo'
foo
```

Comment: `awk 'END{print NR?$0:"default"}'`

Comment: @karakfa Nice and tight, but only works for a single line of output.  `printf "1\n2\n3\n"|awk 'END{print NR?$0:"default"}'` -> `3`

Comment: right, I assumed it returns a value but perhaps a wrong assumption if the return value may contain newlines...

Answer (score 4):

```
echo foo | sed 's/^$/default/'
```

Output:

```
foo
```

---

```
echo | sed 's/^$/default/'
```

Output:

```
default
```

Comment: Agreed, if "empty string" in the question means "blank line", and if that's the only output in cases where the default should be triggered.  `sed 's/^$/default/'</dev/null` produces no output, for example.  I think the question could be read either way.

Comment: Try `printf "%s\n" 1 "" 3 |sed 's/^$/default/'`, and default appears in the middle of your output.

Answer (score 2):

You can miss empty lines with

```
myCommand | grep . || echo 'default'
```

so you might prefer the comment of @BenjaminW. :

```
var=$(myCommand)
echo "${var:-default}"
```